# Extract day from non standard Unix date

Tags: date, unix

I can see that UNIX easily handles a standard date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Date function can easily extract day form standard date format like this

```
date -d '2016-12-9 00:00:00' '+%d'
output: 09
```

But I can't figure out a way to get the same result using a non-standard date format. My date format is '`mm-dd-yyyy`'.

Comment: Do you really want to use date? Why can't extract what you want? Can you give some real example and what you expect?

Comment: @Ali: I have modified my answer to suit `mm-dd-yyyy` format input date.

Answer (score 1):

`GNU date` which you are most likely using because of the `-d` switch, doesn't allow custom formatting of dates, unlike the `FreeBSD` version which supports with the `-f input_fmt` for converting custom date formats.

With `GNU date` and bit of manipulation with `sed`, you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Using `sed` converting your input date in `mm-dd-yyyy` to a format `GNU date` can understand.

```
customDate=$(echo "12-09-2016 00:00:00" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\-\([0-9]\{4\}\) \(.*\)/\3-\1-\2 \4/')
```

Now `customDate` will have the date in the format `2016-12-09 00:00:00` format which you can pass to `-d` flag to get the required date. i.e.

```
date -d "$customDate" '+%d'
09
```

Or as a fancy "one-liner" they call it these days, without the use of the temporary variable.

```
date -d "$(echo "12-09-2016 00:00:00" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\-\([0-9]\{4\}\) \(.*\)/\3-\1-\2 \4/')" '+%d'
09
```